# Syntax for running Octave script by Crontab

Tags: cron, octave

A basic Octave test script, check_octave_crontab.m, is

```
## create some data
cd /path/to/the/required/octave/directory
x = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ] ;
dlmwrite( 'crontab_test_file' , x ) ;
```

and the cronjob is

```
2,22,42 * * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/octave '/home/path/to/this/octave/script/check_octave_crontab.m'
```

but no plot is plotted.

/usr/local/bin/octave is a shared library which points to an octave-5.1.0 shared library, which is my installed version of Octave compiled from source. What do I need to change in the crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no DISPLAY in this case. I run my scripts from crontab with

```
xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout -a --server-args "-screen 0 1920x1080x24" /usr/local/bin/octave myscript.m
```

Comment: The function I gave was just an example. My intended use will be to download data from the web and append to file(s) already on disc without actually plotting anything.

Comment: Why do you ask a question where you obviously say that "but no plot is plotted" and then, that it's not even your intend do generate a plot?

Comment: I have taken onboard your implied criticism and changed my basic Octave test script to more closely reflect what I want to do and now the given crontab job is working. If it hadn't been for your criticism, I wouldn't have realised that my naive choice of test function was the problem, and not the crontab syntax. I've therefore accepted this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your repy and beeing willing to learn. The typical problem with users using cronjobs for the first time is that they don't understand taht their environment vars are completly different (no DISPLAY, no user and so on) I reverted my downvote and gave and upvote